# HTML table can't remove borders

Tags: html, css

I know this might be trivial, but I really can't figure out what's going wrong.

I can't remove the borders from my table.

[image]

Here is the HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: none;padding: 0">
```

I also tried

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:0;padding: 0" class="nothing">
```

but it was no use. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like more CSS is going on than what you posted. Can you post the rest?

Comment: it could also be margin ...

Comment: I suspect the tds to have borders set by css.

Comment: Great guess PRPGFerret and acme, I found out the all TDs have borders on them, Thanks guys

Comment: The `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes are deprecated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should also set `border:none;` and `outline:none;` for the td element (not only for the table itself)  and `border-collapse: collapse;`

Since you're having the class "nothing", try:

```
.nothing
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
} 
.nothing td
{
   border:none;
   outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Since I had to set td borders to zero then this would be the right answer.

Comment: I wonder what year "border-collapse" was added, because I don't remember having this problem from 1994-2004 (back when I used tables.)

Answer (score 5):

Try `border-collapse: collapse`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
style="border-collapse: collapse;"
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<table style="border-style: hidden;">
```

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `This does not provide an answer to the question`, to maximise your chance of getting your answer **[accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** and **[upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.